# python - urllib2 request not returning all html

Tags: python

I am trying to get a sense of the different cases of using urllib2 to read web content and there seems to be some check going on at the gifts.com website that is preventing me from reading all the html.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.gifts.com'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36')
page = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
print soup
```

I had a similar issue in the past but was able to fix it by adding the 'User-Agent' header but this seems to be some javascript check that is preventing access... the result is all of the page content up to:

```
>>><script>var readyStateHandlerPDP = document.onreadystatechange;var AddPDPPrefetchFiles = function (SiteVersionData) {var _siteVersionNumber = SiteVersionData.GetSiteVersionNumber();var onDeferredLoadPDP = function () {/* append prefetch files for PDP to head */var head = $('head');head.append('<link rel="prefetch" href="//static.prvd.com/client/javascript/harmony/harmonytop.min.js?v=' + _siteVersionNumber + '">');head.append('<link rel="prefetch" href="//static.prvd.com/client/javascript/pdpcommon/pdpcommon.min.js?v=' + _siteVersionNumber + '">');head.append('<link rel="prefetch" href="//static.prvd.com/client/javascript/harmony/harmony.min.js?v=' + _siteVersionNumber + '">');head.append('<link rel="prefetch" href="//www.proflowers.com/product/controls/harmonytemplates/harmonytemplates.aspx?v=' + _siteVersionNumber + '">');};if (!readyStateHandlerPDP) {document.onreadystatechange = function () {if (document.readyState === "complete")onDeferredLoadPDP();}} else {readyStateHandlerPDP();onDeferredLoadPDP();}}(window.SiteVersionData);</script
<link href="http://static.prvd.com/client/stylesheets/widgets/pseudoproduct.css?v=2016.2.24.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/></meta></meta></meta></meta></meta></head></html>
```

where the page abruptly ends, even though the html continues if I go to the site and view the page source.

I don't have any interest in masking my identity or making an anonymous request so any help on how to best mimic normal web browsing in order to pass this check would be helpful.

Comment: Note that `urllib2` does not execute any javascript at all, so any page content that is created using javascript will not appear in your data. Try to find a third-party "headless browser" library that executes JS.

Comment: More likely, the page is using that Javascript to load the rest of the content in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `urllib2` cannot execute javascript, it can only load plain HTML. In order to be able to execute JavaScript you'll need to use some api to drive a  web browser that can execute JavaScript.

Some examples would be:

- [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py)
- [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html)

Comment: you are correct.  thanks for the recommendations - selenium works great.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. I definitely prefer using selenium too.